# Pony ages in My Little Pony: Friendship Is Magic

Tags: my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim

What is the actual age of the following ponies:

- Twilight Sparkle
- Pinkie Pie
- Rarity
- Apple Jack
- Rainbow Dash
- Fluttershy
- Princess Luna
- Princess Celestia
- Granny Smith

So let's add some constraints:

- They live on their own.
- Fluttershy is one year older than Pinkie Pie.
- Princess Luna were banished to the moon for 1000 years.
- Princess Celestia is older than Princess Luna.
- Princess Celestia is around 10,000 years old in the premiere
- Despite the fact that Granny Smith looks pretty old, Princess Luna and Celestia don't.
- Spike is younger than Twilight Sparkle, (I know that Spike is not a pony).
- We know that Twilight Sparkle has coursed magic kindergarten, so we can assume that she is at least 6 years old.
- Since no pony is studying in a college, we can assume that they're at least 17 or older.
- After reviewing some chapters, I found out that Rainbow Dash is at least 20% cooler than any other pony.
- We know that the main six are obviously  teenagers, since they are in high school. That  means they about 13.
- Look at fillies. They are in high school in **Equestria Girls**. That means they could be 14 or 15. Ponies are older than that.

Comment: Don't forget that Luna and Celestia are alicorn gods, while granny smith isn't.

Comment: I don't know if it's ever really been said, though it seems like most of the main characters are at least in their early 20s, given that they're all living on their own.

Comment: @thedaian Or at least at the pony equivalent of early 20s.

Comment: Whomever voted to close. This is a constructive question. Silly, but constructive.

Comment: It is sad that [tag:friendship-is-magic] has 0 followers

Comment: One thing I don't understand is why Rarity is taking care of Sweetie Bell?  I'd previously assumed all the ponies were orphans (except for Twilight Sparkle, as we saw her parents in a previous episode).  But then Rarity and Sweetie Bell's parents show up, and there's no explanation for why her sister is raising her.

Comment: Everything from "so lets add some constraints" is really an *answer* (albeit an incomplete one), not part of the question.  You should edit that part out (and perhaps add a little bit of an explanation of why it's worth knowing this) and add it as an answer that someone can build on.

Comment: This question seems to fall into a grey area of sorts. Technically it's valid, but then so would all questions of the form "What is the <attribute> of <character> in <show>?" Unless it is somehow relevant to the plot, that is. Also, is My Little Pony technically fantasy?

Comment: @HNL: There are talking animals with magical powers.  If it's *not* fantasy then we're going to have a category problem with Narnia.

Comment: @Tynam: That's what I thought. I'm not very familiar with these creatures, but are their ages significant or is it merely trivia? I believe we should avoid trivia. Also the second tag seems superfluous.

Comment: Friendship **is** magic and it definitely isn't superfluous!!!

Comment: I think I love everything about this question.

Comment: @Keen Rarity isn't raising Sweetie Bell full-time; apparently she just babysits a lot. There's no bedroom for Sweetie in Rarity's house/shop, and it's shown to be a major burden when she's around.

Comment: @Yamikuronue Good point.  The lack of parental units has thrown my understanding of what's going on.

Comment: @Keen: it's more of a matter of circumstances than anything - the Mane 6 are old enough to live on their own (save Applejack, who lives with her family) and the rest of the supporting cast isn't shown quite enough to extend to parents (save the Cakes and Pumpkin/Pound Cake).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From Lauren Faust's [Deviant Art Page](http://fyre-flye.deviantart.com/journal/FAQ-276161988)

> Q: How old are the ponies?
>
> A: The ponies' ages were left intentionally undefined.  I like to think of them as having  maturity levels anywhere between 12 and 18, (but remember that maturity is different than age.  You can be a 10-year-old with the maturity of a 15-year-old, and you can be a 35-year-old with the maturity of a 15-year-old.)  For story telling purposes, they needed to be able to live independent of parents, but innocent enough for the type of lessons they learn at the end of the episodes.   Since horses are full grown around 5-ish, I guess I sort of justified it in my head that they could be childlike young adults.  I know this answer is frustrating for some people, but it happens often in cartoons.  How old is Bugs Bunny?  Mickey Mouse?  Sponge Bob?  I don't know either.

So it's undefined, but it's strongly implied that they are 3-5 years old in pony years. I highly doubt this is their actual age, and I suspect MLP ponies age differently to RL ponies.

**Edit**: I've just checked [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horse#Lifespan_and_life_stages) and the oldest age for a <strike>pony</strike> horse is 30 years, though that is only the average. Some unusual horses live to be 40, with the oldest pony at 57. Let us assume that Granny smith is about 50. She's *old* but not so old as to be dying all too soon.  If we make her at about 200 years old in MLP years (due to her being there at the start of ponyville which is centuries old), that makes an age contraction of about 1:4. Then checking back to Wiki, any <strike>horse</strike> pony older than 4 years is a Mare or a Stallion. I'd then place their ages between 16 and 20. We've got to bare in mind this though:

> Regardless of a horse's actual birth date, for most competition purposes, an animal is considered a year older on January 1 of each year in the Northern Hemisphere and August 1 in the Southern Hemisphere. The exception is in endurance riding, where the minimum age to compete is based on the animal's actual calendar age.

I think we're safe in the assumption that we're in the northern hemisphere. From this all the ponies ages are 'the same', except Applejack who is probably considered a year older due to using her actual date of birth, I'd make her ~5 but only just and living with such young friends makes for her not acting her age. I'd probably sum all of this up to say they're all about 17-18 in MLP years (4-5 in RL pony years). In the episode "Griffon the Brush-Off" Fluttershy retorts to a line said by Pinkie Pie by saying "I'm a year older than you", which could either be interpreted in pony years or our years, giving the age of either 5 pony years or something like 19 or 20 of our years. Another thing is how Pinkie is actually far smarter than she initially seems, implying much more maturity (which again implies age) than at first glance.

That makes our best guess something like this (to the nearest year) in RL/MLP terms:

- **Twilight Sparkle** - *4/18* (fresh out of magic school)
- **Pinky Pie** - *4/18*
- **Rarity** - *4/18*
- **Apple Jack** - *5/20*
- **Rainbow Dash** - *4/19* (rounding down to 4 due to the January birth thing)
- **Fluttershy** - *5/19 or 20* (based off of the questions premise)
- **Princess Luna** - *Indeterminant, minimum 1000, although unclear*
- **Princess Celestia** - *Indeterminant, minimum 1000, although unclear*
- **Granny Smith** - *50/200*

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer *more*.

Comment: That's an odd definition of "one year older", though I suppose it works. I always assumed that line was an in-universe year over an RL year.

Comment: @RCIX I'm trying to make a good answer out of a lot of approximations, there will be some fudging involved. Just sit back and enjoy the answer :)

Comment: You can make an Equestria-based estimate as of Apple Family Reunion, which places Apple Jack as a toddler about 200 "moons" ago.

Comment: @tacroy if I get around to catching up I'll work that in.

Comment: 200 moons ie months is roughly 17 years.  But considering every night is a full moon and seasons don't even work that way, moons is a horrible in universe measure of time.

Answer (score 14):

New info from *Pinkie Pride*: Rainbow Dash's birthday cake has 21 candles visible.

That said, we don't see the reverse side of the cake (where there could be more candles), and the celebration is Rainbow's "Birthiversary" -- a simultaneous celebration of her birthday and the anniversary of her arrival in Ponyville, so the candle count could be a combination of the two.

[image: Rainbow's Birthday Cake]

Comment: This is incredible relevant!

Comment: In the season 2 episode "Baby Cakes", Pinkie Pie mentions the tradition of having as many candles as the pony's age, so that rule definitely exists in Equestria.

Answer (score 11):

Granny Smith is at least a couple of hundred years old. This is shown in *Family Appreciation Day* as she is one of the first to settle in Ponyville and in *Winter Wrap Up*, Twilight Sparkle says that Ponyville's been wrapping up winter for hundreds of years without magic. Just put two and two together and you can tell Granny Smith must be at least a hundred years old.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know a lot about pony aging, but I'm pretty sure I have a solid ageing system for the cast in human years - translate them to pony years if you wish - but then the Fluttershy = Pinkie Pie + 1 rule jams it up a bit.

RULES AND OBSERVATIONS:

- Assuming that pony school, pegasi school, and magic school start at
  the same time.
- Fluttershy is older than Rainbow Dash.
- They are all considered adults.
- I'm using flashbacks as references.
- I'm using height and sizes.
- Also using season 1 episode 23 flashbacks.
- That all the schools begin enrolling at the age of six.
- Fluttershy is the largest, tallest, longlegged, wide wingspanned, and
  is already enrolled in school (enrolled two years prior to Twilight,
  one year above everyone else).
- Rainbow Dash is also enrolled in the same school but is younger than
  Fluttershy.
- Rarity is already enrolled in a school, and is allowed access to
  sharp objects for making costumes.
- Apple Jack is old enough that her guardians let her travel alone to a
  big city, though is similar in size to Rarity and Rainbow Dash
  (since they don't
  show Apple Jack attending or enrolling school and I'm using school and size as a guide, my guess for her is
  uncertain).
- Pinkie Pie never attended school. She presumably went from working at a rock farm to
  working in a bakery shop. She is the same size as Rainbow Dash, Apple Jack and Rarity.
- Twilight is barely enrolled for school, but she is the same size as all but Fluttershy.

AGES:

1. Fluttershy is the oldest at the age of 20 (one year older than Pinky and
   enrolled two years prior to RD so she's much larger).
2. Apple Jack and Pinkie Pie are 19 (AJ and PP never attended school, at
   least as shown, but AJ does mention getting her cutie mark last).
3. Rainbow Dash and Rarity are 18 (RD and Rarity both were enrolled at the same year. That's why they are the same size).
4. Twilight Sparkle is the youngest at 17 years old (She is Princess Celestia's protege, but she was sent to Ponyville to CONTINUE her studies, therefore she hasn't graduated yet. She is also scared of being held back/sent back grades, inplying that she is still in school).

Answer (score 4):

I know as much as-
Celestia
Luna
Granny Smith.

I would expect Applejack to be the eldest of the Mane 6, as she was the last in her class to get her Cutie Mark, Dash was the first. I think that Dash and Pinkie Pie are the youngest.

Comment: Wouldn't that make Applejack the youngest?

Answer (score 2):

I think the most reasonable explanation would be to say that regular ponies age at the same rate as humans. For example, a six year old pony would be the same as a human child. I base this off Crystalis' comment to Pinkie Pie in A Canterlot Wedding.

So, the mane six are in their late teens, although they don't always act like it. Alicorns are either immortal or have very long lives. Princess Luna is physiologically not much older than the mane six, and about the same as Princess Cadence. Speaking of who, Cadence doesn't seem to be as powerful as Luna and Celestia, so she may age like regular ponies even though she's an alicorn. It may explain why she chose to marry and why Luna and Celestia never have.

As for Granny Smith, let's look back at our own history these last hundred years. Even as cars and electric lights were being created, there were still Civil War veterans alive. So I'd say Granny Smith is at least 90 years old, and that the age of Ponyville was exaggerated.

Answer (score 2):

Oh ok. I think my ages were SLIGHTly irrational. Pinkie lives and works for strangers?! That invalidates my guess for Pinkie. So I would start a baseline age for... Let's say 15. The only thing, is that she is really hyper and weird (ADHD, i believe) which scales her age down and the reason why I put her as 10. So I'll upscale the ages of the mane 6... (Multiply by 1.5, rounded down) Also Fluttershy is 1 pony year older, not 2.2.

- As I said, Pinkie Pie is 15. By the end of season 2, she must be 19 to 21.
- Twilight Sparkle is 18. This is valid, because she is fresh out of magic school. By the end of season 2, she must be 22 to 24.
- Rainbow Dash is 16. By the end of season 2, she must be 20 to 22.
- Apple Jack is 22.
- From the premises, Flutter Shy is 16 as well. This is valid, as they were friends for a long time. By the end of season 2, she must be 20 to 22.
- Rarity is 24.
- Celestia and Luna must have been existing from the Creation (I am Christian) MUST certainly be at least 2200 and may be at least 13200 (Creation happened around 4000BC) and Celestia is older than Luna.
- Spike is 13 (Correction, 18-5). Twilight got him when she was five.
  Granny Smith's age would STILL be 453-897 (1 human year is 2.2 pony years and 2-4 centuries would be reasonable. Also, she may have been 13 to 17 before Equestria was started.) Then again, that's pretty old.
- Shining Armor should be 22-23 in human years (captain in the royal guard, which is comparative to the Marines or so)

The conclusion is still the same.

-Cherry Flu.

Answer (score 1):

I think they would have to be at least 17/18 due to the fact that they live alone and work..

Applejack will probably be the oldest because she said she got her cutie Mark last in her class ect. But earth pony school, magic school and flight school might have different starting ages and/or different grades so its kinda hard to judge.

I reckon they are about 19-21 with AJ and Rarity being the oldest and Rainbow and Fluttershy being the younger of the 6.

Im certain Pinkie is much older than she seems due to the fact that she lives with and works for strangers(as in not family) and is allowed to foalsit their young foals by herself.

I think enough has been said about Granny Smith, Luna and Celestia so Ill leave it at that. ^ - ^

Answer (score 0):

We got some new information from this week's episode, S5 E11 Party Pooped.  In this episode, Applejack finds some notes about future parties Pinkie Pie is planning.

> Looky here. It's notes for the party she wants to throw for her folks' fiftieth anniversary. But they ain't nearly that old!

That probably refers to the wedding anniversary of Pinkie Pie's mother and father.  Their wedding was probably before Pinkie Pie was born, or not much after, so this means Pinkie Pie and Fluttershy are much younger than 50 years old.  (Alternately, this could refer to some other family member, or the Cakes, who treat Pinkie Pie as familiy.)

---

Now some information from earlier episodes.  In S3 E8 Apple Family Reunion, Granny Smith says they've been holding reunions every hundred month since Ponyville was founded, and Auntie Applesauce mentions there has been at least six reunions before this one, which makes Ponyville at least 56 years old.

Answer (score -1):

- I assume. That what is being said in all the comments, they would be
  17-20 years old. Since they are living home alone. Besides Pinkie Pie.
- Applejack, Being the middle child of the Apple family, and a
  worker for the family, and of course being the last to get her
  cutie mark in her class, I would put her the oldest or second
  oldest of the Mane 6.
- To why Granny Smith looks old and wrinkly like she does, Luna and her sister are
  Alicorns, and are immortal. They cannot die from age. So to add
  common sense to add to this concept, if somepony is an immortal. You
  would reach your max height, and looks, and stay that way. (AKA: Looks young forever)
- For the ages of Fluttershy and Rainbow Dash, well, you could say they
  may be the youngest of the other 6 ponies, but to me, I put them in
  the middle. Let’s start with this though before going to Rainbow Dash
  and Fluttershy ages, I myself could put Pinkie Pie around... 18 or 17 years of age- She
  foalsits and she bakes at Sugar Cube Corner, and lives with strangers
  she trusts. Would you trust a kid to be left alone at your house to cook and
  baby sit your kids? I would not.
- And now to Fluttershy. Fluttershy did say in an episode of My Little Pony she is a year older then Pinkie Pine. And as I said. Pinkie Pie is 17 or 18, so that means she is 18 or 19 years old.
- For Rainbow Dash? I coooould say she is the same age as Pinkie Pie or Fluttershy, so 17-19 years old.
- Reason for putting Fluttershy and Dashie close of age is,since
  Dasihe and Fluttershy known each other since they were young and in flight school.
- Now to Rarity. She owns her own tailor shop and makes her own clothes. So she can be around 20s? She could be hitching the same road with Applejack in the 20’s. To exactly tell who is the oldest between the two? Or if they are the same age. Not sure, but I would put them early 20's.
- For Twilight Sparkle? I could put her between the ages of... 16-19.
  Because Twilight being out of school in a manners of sorts, and being out of
  kindergarten school at that as well.
- And being the baby sister of Shining Armor, who Shining may be
  around 30’s, due to him being the captain of the Royal Guard.
- And to add more common sense to this whole statement, since she is
  getting private schooling from Celestia, I would assume she may be
  the youngest of the mane 6, placing her at the age of 16.

.

- So a recap
  .  Applejack: 20-23

  - Rarity: 20-23
  - Twilight Sparkle: Assuming my best guess. 16.
  - Rainbow Dash: 18
  - Flutter shy: 19
  - Pinkie Pie: 18
  - Granny Smith: She's pretty old, probably around 100.
  - Luna and Celestia are almost the same age only one or two years different. Maybe they are about 1000 years old

Comment: Could you please transform this wall of text into something more readable?

Answer (score -2):

Being an animal and aging differently than humans, they're very young. If I was being a realist, a horse's life expectancy is only 20 to 30 years. A pony that is a couple months old may be equal to a human child, and a year old pony would be equal to a teen and so on.

I disagree with the other comments saying they are 15 or 17 because they would be old. The only ponies that look young forever are the unicorn gods. Time in that realm must be different, probably a human month would be like several months to them, or even a year. 
This logic is based off of a horse's actual life span.

If this is not the case and their ages are equivalent to human years and time, then their ages are probably like 12 to 14 and at the most, 16. But it's hard to tell because everyone in the show has the personality of a little kid, same with Spongebob.